# Can isc-dhcp-server update bind running on a non default port?

Tags: bind, dhcp, ddns

I'm running the following on the same server:  pi-hole, bind9, isc-dhcp-server and cloudflared (for DNS over HTTPS).  The order goes like this:

Pihole:53 -> Bind9:54 -> cloudflared:5353

I'm now installing isc-dhcp-server to act as my authoritative DHCP server, since my ubiquity router can't really maintain hostnames that well, and it doesn't update dns (uses a host file).  I've set up DDNS before in the past, but now that I have pi-hole running on the standard dns port (53), I'm not sure dynamic updates will work correctly.

I've tried looking at the manual for ISC-dhcp-server but all I can find for the primary dns is an IP, no option for port.   So my question is, how does isc-dhcp-server update bind?  I know it uses a TSIG key for authentication, but will it still work with bind running on another port?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are right, ISC dhcpd does not appear to have an option to specify the port for the nameserver to send dynamic updates to.

A straightforward solution would be to have the different nameservers (at least the ones you need to work on the standardized port for DNS) bind to port 53 on different IP addresses instead of binding to different ports.

Eg:

- Pihole 192.168.1.1:53
- BIND 127.0.0.1:53
- ...

Comment: thanks for confirming my suspicion.  I'll change bind's ip to the local ip.  Thanks!